In pgloader loading csv file and i want to skip a row from file if specific column value is null
Loading csv file in pgloader using load file and I want to skip rows based on column condition for example if specific column value is null then i want to skip that row
Not able to get the approach how to do that in pgloader please help me thankyou in advance.

You need to add materialize view and it will be migrated to postgres. Demo script is as follows:
LOAD DATABASE
FROM mysql://root:admin@localhost/test_db
INTO postgresql://postgres:admin@localhost:5428/test_db
WITH include drop, create tables, create indexes, reset sequences, foreign keys
SET maintenance_work_mem to '128MB', work_mem to '12MB', search_path to 'public'
CAST type datetime to timestamptz using zero-dates-to-null,
type date drop default drop not null using zero-dates-to-null
MATERIALIZE VIEWS filtered_peoples
BEFORE LOAD DO
$$ CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS public; $$;

How does this apply to the question? The question is asking about importing a CSV file, not transferring a MySQL database to Postgres.
